# Drap and drop list items to generate event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need to perform a drag and drop operation and detect the corresponding event based dropped item.
Here the image describes a typical UI I want to create.

[image]

"NAME LIST" is populated with list of names. "NAME 1" and "NAME 2" are boxes where I'd drop the name from "NAME LIST". Both boxes would be populated with dropped items. After dropping in single name box or both. The red region fires up with text, for example "name1=tom and name2=tim". Also, "NAME LIST" remains static  (i.e, no items are deleted). I should also be able to remove names from "NAME 1" and "NAME 2" boxes.

I have checked html5 and jquery and it has the option of drag and drop effect. 
Before I learn more about these options, can someone who has already worked on these, point me to any existing plugins/libraries I must look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI brings all the UI functionality you asking for.

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

This is very much like your example:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart